# Shopware 6 : How to get plugin configuration value in product detail page

Tags: shopware

I want to show/hide button on product detail page based on plugin configuration value, but don't know how to do this.Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The config should be available under the shopware object like:

```
{% if shopware.config.{yourConfigKey} %}
   <button></button>
{% endif %}
```